# I have an R.Layout.main error on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

R.layout.main Cannot Be Found/Can not Resolve Symbol R

It’ll flag all my layout resource files as containing these errors., which makes it difficult to know where to start looking for the source of the error. please help me

Comment: Can you share screen short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try File->Invalidate Caches and Restart?

Comment: I had the same problem and this helped me. Then I did Build->Clean Project & Build->Rebuild Project.

Comment: No problem. Can you accept my answer, so it shows the green check mark on the side. "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."

Comment: Done .... can u please upvote my question ... So that I gain some reputation ... And ask a question with images plz